# ASP.Net Update panel nightmare. Button doesnt fire properly. Web form c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, webforms

I load have two link to load Comment.aspx  as modal popup using Ajax ModalPopup.

One link is an LinkBuuton that open the same Comment.aspx in ModalPopup1 and other link is a Submit button that Post comment that also load the same page in another Modalpopup2. I use jQuery to trap the click even and load the Comment.aspx page in respected ModalPopup's .

Problem is that when i open the "mpShowCommentPopUp" popup using link button  "lnkBtnComment" it works fine and shows inline validation without any problem.

But now if i close this Popup and try to load the same Comment.aspx using Button "btnPostComment2" in this scenario  button doesn't fire.

And in case if i refresh the page and now i first open the Comment.aspx page using lnkBtnComment" this time it will work and validation will show without any issue and if i repeat the step one then again button wont fire.

I am placing the Partial MainPage code  and the comment.aspx code in

```
<%@ Page Title="" UICulture="Auto" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ArticleDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="ArticleDetails"  %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=lnkBtnEmail.ClientID %>").click(function(){
                //Load EMail Form
                $("#<%=pnlEmailArticleForm.ClientID %>").load("EmailArticle.aspx?ArticleID=<%=Request["ArticleID"] %>&Language=<%=Request["Language"] %>", function () {  });
                // $(".formErrorContent").show();             // $(".formErrorArrow").show();
            });

            //Close popup
               $("#<%= imgBtnCloseEmailPopup.ClientID %>").click(function () { $('#frmEmail').validationEngine('hideAll')
                // $(".formErrorContent").hide();             //  $(".formErrorArrow").hide();
             });


            $("#<%=btnPostComment2.ClientID %>").click(function(){
                //Load Comment Form
                $("#<%=pnlCommentForm2.ClientID %>").load("Comment.aspx?ArticleID=<%=Request["ArticleID"] %>&Language=<%=Request["Language"] %>", function () {      });
             });
            $("#<%= imgBtnClose2.ClientID %>").click(function () {  $('#frmComment').validationEngine('hideAll')  });


             $("#<%= lnkBtnComment.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                //Load Comment Form
                $("#<%=pnlCommentForm.ClientID %>").load("Comment.aspx?ArticleID=<%=Request["ArticleID"] %>&Language=<%=Request["Language"] %>", function (){       });
                });
              $("#<%= imgBtnClose.ClientID %>").click(function () {  $('#frmComment').validationEngine('hideAll')  });



         });

         //For printing
         function CallPrint() {
             window.open('PrintArticle.aspx?articleID=<%=Request["articleID"] %>', 'Email', 'width=690, height=650,left=100, top=100, location=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=yes, status=no, toolbar=no,fullscreen=no');
         }
         //For printing
         function CallDownload() {
             window.open('PrintArticle.aspx?articleID=<%=Request["articleID"] %>&download=yes', 'Email', 'width=690, height=650,left=100, top=100, location=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=no, status=no, toolbar=no,fullscreen=no');
         }
    </script>

<style type="text/css">
        .modalBackground
        {
        background-color: Gray;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        opacity: 0.8;
        z-index: 10000;
        }
        .bodyClass
        {
            background: url(~/images/content_repeat.jpg) repeat-xy;
            background-color:#E5E5E5;
        }
        </style>
<script type="text/javascript" >
                function showHelloWorld() {
                    //alert('Hello World');
                    return true;
                }

                //-->
        </script>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <div id="container" class="container">
        <div id="TopBanner" class="TopBanner"><asp:Image ID="imgTopBanner" runat="server" /> </div>
        <div id="TopBannerBase" class="TopBannerBase" ></div>
    </div>
  <div id="bodyContainer"  class="bodyContainer">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  >
                <tr>
                    <td width="35px"></td>
                    <td width="826px" valign="top">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="826px">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="40px" width="826px" >
                                    <div class="breadcrum" >
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyLkHomeNav" runat="server"  CssClass="goldNav" NavigateUrl="default.aspx"  ></asp:HyperLink> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="breadcrum">
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyLkPageNav" runat="server" CssClass="goldNav" ></asp:HyperLink> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="breadcrum">
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyLnkYear" runat="server" CssClass="goldNav" ></asp:HyperLink> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="breadcrum">
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hylnkArticleTitle" runat="server" CssClass="goldNav" ></asp:HyperLink> 
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblArtcleTitleNav" CssClass="navActiveCurrent" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPageName" runat="server" Height="16px" Visible="False"  Width="16px"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td height="35px" width="826px">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="826px" >
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="400px" valign="top">

                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td height="30px">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblArticleTitle" CssClass="ArticleTitleText" runat="server" Text="" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
                                                        <div id="articlePubdate" Class="ArticlePubDate" >
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblPublished" runat="server" Text="Published : "></asp:Label>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblPubDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td height="2px" bgcolor="#D1C094"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="text-align:justify" >

                                                       <div id="divArticleImage" class="divArticleImage" runat="server">
                                                           <asp:Image ID="imgArticle" CssClass="ArticleImage" runat="server" />
                                                           <div id="divArticleImageDesc" class="divArticleImageDesc" >
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblImgDesc" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                           </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                       <asp:Label ID="lblArticleDetails" CssClass="PageBodyText" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td >
                                                <table class="divArticleDetailsFooter"><tr><td>
                                                <!-- Article Details Section footer -->
                                                <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                                                <div id="divArticleDetailsFooter"  class="divArticleDetailsFooter">
                                                    <div id="divlblComment" class="imgTArticleDetailsFooter">
                                                    <asp:Image ID="imgComment" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/comment.png"  />
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnComment" runat="server" 
                                                            CssClass="divArticleDetailsFooterLabels" CausesValidation="False" 
                                                            onclick="lnkBtnComment_Click" >Comment</asp:LinkButton>

                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="divlblEmail" class="imgTArticleDetailsFooter">
                                                    <asp:Image ID="imgEmail" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/email.png" />
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnEmail" runat="server"  
                                                         CssClass="divArticleDetailsFooterLabels" CausesValidation="True" 
                                                            onclick="lnkBtnEmail_Click" >Email</asp:LinkButton>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="divlblPrint" class="imgTArticleDetailsFooter">
                                                    <asp:Image ID="imgPrint" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/print.png" />
                                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hylPrintArticle" runat="server" CssClass="divArticleDetailsFooterLabels" OnClick="CallPrint()" NavigateUrl=""> Print</asp:HyperLink>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <div id="divlblDownload" class="imgTArticleDetailsFooter">
                                                    <asp:Image ID="imgDownload" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/download.png" />
                                                   <asp:HyperLink ID="hylDownloadArticle" runat="server" CssClass="divArticleDetailsFooterLabels" OnClick="CallDownload()" NavigateUrl=""> Download</asp:HyperLink>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>  
                                                <!-- Article Details Section footer -->
                                                </td></tr></table>
                                                </td></tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td height="20px" ></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td height="2px" bgcolor="#D1C094"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td height="100px" >
                                                    <div id="showComments" class="showComments">
                                                        <div id="divCommentCount" class="CommentCount"><asp:Label ID="lblCommentCount" runat="server" Text="Comment"></asp:Label> </div>
                                                        <div id="divPostCommentMSG" class="PostCommentMSG"><asp:Label ID="lblPostCommentMSG" runat="server" Text="Please keep your comments relevant to this website entry. Email addresses are never displayed, but they are required to confirm your comments. Please note that gratuitous links to your site are viewed as spam and may result in removed comments."></asp:Label></div>
                                                        <div id="divPostCommentButton" class="divPostCommentButton"> 
                                                            <asp:Button ID="btnPostComment2" runat="server" CssClass="buttonPC" 
                                                                Text="Post Comment" CausesValidation="False" 
                                                                onclick="btnPostComment2_Click" /></div>
                                                        <div>Line</div>
                                                        <div>Post Date</div>
                                                        <div>Message</div>
                                                        <div>Person Name</div>
                                                        <div>line</div>

                                                    </div>

                                                     </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </td>
                    <td width="39px" valign="top">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</div>

<div>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpShowCommentPopUp" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkBtnComment" PopupControlID="pnlComment"
 BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="imgBtnClose" RepositionMode="None" ></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

     <asp:Panel ID="pnlComment" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="400px" Width="520px" style="display:none">
         <div id="divcommentForm" class="commentForm">
            <div id="divClose" class="commentClose">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnClose" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/close.png" CausesValidation="False"  />
            </div>
            <!-- comment Form -->

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlCommentForm" runat="server" Visible="true">

            </asp:Panel>
            <!-- comment Form -->
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>

<div>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpShowCommentPopUp2" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnPostComment2" PopupControlID="pnlComment2"
 BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="imgBtnClose2" RepositionMode="None" ></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

     <asp:Panel ID="pnlComment2" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="400px" Width="520px" style="display:none">
         <div id="divcommentForm2" class="commentForm">
            <div id="divClose2" class="commentClose">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnClose2" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/images/close.png" CausesValidation="False"  />
            </div>
            <!-- comment Form -->
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlCommentForm2" runat="server" Visible="true">

            </asp:Panel>
            <!-- comment Form -->
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>

<div>
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpShowEmailArticlePopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkBtnEmail" PopupControlID="pnlEmailArticle"
     BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="imgBtnCloseEmailPopup" RepositionMode="None"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
          <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailArticle" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="350px" Width="520px" >
             <div id="emailArticle" class="EmailArticleForm">
                 <div id="closeEmailArticle" class="commentClose">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnCloseEmailPopup" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/close.png" onclick="imgBtnCloseEmailPopup_Click" CausesValidation="False"  /> 
                 </div>
                 <!-- Email Form -->
                 <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailArticleForm" runat="server" Visible="true">

                 </asp:Panel>
                 <!-- Email Form -->
                 </div>
        </asp:Panel>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Main Page Partial Code c#**

```
protected void imgBtnCloseEmailPopup_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.mpShowEmailArticlePopup.Show();
}

protected void lnkBtnComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.mpShowCommentPopUp.Show();
}
protected void lnkBtnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.mpShowEmailArticlePopup.Show();
}
protected void btnPostComment2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.mpShowCommentPopUp2.Show();
}
```

**Comment.aspx Page Code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" UICulture="Auto" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Comment.aspx.cs" Inherits="Comment" EnableViewStateMac="False" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  >
<head id="Head1" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
    <title></title>
    <% if (Session["lang"] == "ar-AE")
       { %>
        <link href="~/Styles/arabic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <% } else { %>
        <link href="~/Styles/english.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <% } %>
    <link href="Scripts/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/js/jquery.validationEngine-ar.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            //jQuery("#Form2").validationEngine();
            <% if( Session["lang"] =="ar-AE") %>
            jQuery("#frmComment").validationEngine({ promptPosition: 'topLeft', scroll: false });
            <%else %>
            jQuery("#frmComment").validationEngine({ promptPosition: 'topRight', scroll: false });
            <% %>

           // $("#frmComment").validationEngine('attach');
            });
    </script>


</head>

<body id="body"  dir="<%=Session["PageDIR"] %>" bgcolor="White">
<form id="frmComment" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlComment" runat="server"  >
 <ContentTemplate>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlCommentForm"  runat="server" Visible="true" >
<div id="commentFormTable" class="commentFormTable">
<table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="460px"  border=0  >
        <tr>
            <td  >
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8" width="460px" >
                    <tr>
                        <td  colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblPostComment" runat="server" Text="Post Comment"  CssClass="lblPostComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td  colspan="2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommentMsg"  CssClass="txtLabelComment" runat="server" Text="Please make sure your comment is not abusive, defamatory or offensive. All 
                            fields must be filled in correctly or the comment will not be approved." 
                                Width="400px" ></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblRequired" CssClass="txtLabelComment" runat="server" Text="[*] indicates a required field."></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="110px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text="Full Name" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td width="340px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server" 
                                CssClass="validate[required] txtbox300Comment" TabIndex="1" ></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;*
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtFullName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Email Address" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" 
                                CssClass="validate[required,custom[email]] txtbox300Comment" TabIndex="2" ></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;*
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv2" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtEmail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text="Country" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCountry" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required] ddGeneralComment" 
                                TabIndex="3">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AF">Afghanistan</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AL">Albania</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="DZ">Algeria</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AS">American Samoa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AD">Andorra</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AO">Angola</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AI">Anguilla</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ZR">Zaire</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ZM">Zambia</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ZW">Zimbabwe</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
                            &nbsp;*<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv3" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="ddCountry"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMSG" runat="server" Text="Your Message" CssClass="txtLabelComment" ></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required, maxSize[1000]] txtbox300MComment" 
                                TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="10" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;*<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv4" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtMessage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAnonymous" runat="server" 
                                Text="I wish to be anonymous. Do not publish my name with my comment. " CssClass="txtLabelComment" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td > &nbsp;</td>
                        <td> 
                        <div>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveComments" runat="server" CssClass="buttonPopups" onclick="btnSaveComments_Click" Text="Post Comment"  />
                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlCommentSuccessMSG" runat="server" Visible="false">
 <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="510px">
        <tr>
            <td height="410px" valign="middle" align="center">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCommentSuccessMSG" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</div>
</asp:Panel>

 </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code i am frustrated with the this and have been working with it from last one week i fix one thing and another think is starts to bread down.

I must mention code works fine as and individual page but bugs start to creep in when i call this page using Ajax Modal Popup along with update panel.

Is there better way to have the same functionality.

I would appreciate any help and a great solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't got an aspx development enviroment, but it seems an javascript did fire. Did you check the error console in Chrome, Safari or Firefox?

Comment: In IE and in debug mode it generates this error if i repeat the above steps mentioned in the question and take me to comment.aspx page with some jabscrips showing on the page itself error

Comment: ERROR: Line: 1786
Error: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Sys.Extended.UI.ModalPopupBehavior' cannot be converted to type 'Sys.UI.Behavior'.
Parameter name: instance

Comment: You are trying to load page and at the same time you do a button postback. You have a jquery script on your comment.aspx and the buttons click on the main page might, whit its postback might interrupt the loading or the other way around. You have to make a sequence of the events: Open Modal, load page

Comment: Working with multiple Ajax Modal Popups in same page doesn't not work properly specially when one is using inline validation. I have decided to not use use it as its behaviors is very unpredictable and i am not an expert in this fields even after 1 week i cant get it right i tried different techniques and fix one problem and later you find other functionality is not working properly. So being not an expert i will leave it for now ad i can spend more time on this. I will use simple old way ( I will open this as a new window without scroll bar, menus etc..)

Answer (score 0):

This might help to get someone in a similar situation through..  This will work if you are registering the script with the scriptmanager on the same page as an updatepanel.

```
Dim strScript As New StringBuilder()
strScript.AppendLine("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
' execute first
strScript.AppendLine(strJavascript)
' register for partialpostbacks
strScript.AppendLine("if(typeof(Sys)!=='undefined'){")
strScript.AppendLine("if(typeof(Sys.WebForms)!=='undefined'){")
strScript.AppendLine("if(typeof(Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager)!=='undefined'){")
strScript.AppendLine("var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();")
strScript.AppendLine("prm.add_endRequest(function(){")
strScript.AppendLine(strJavascript)
strScript.Append("});")
strScript.AppendLine("}")
strScript.AppendLine("}")
strScript.AppendLine("}")
strScript.AppendLine("</script>")
```

However, I'm currently experiencing some difficulties with this implementation using a JQuery wrapper class I setup.  Works great but the class fails when use inside an updatepanel.  Still working that out..ideas are always appreciated!